# Termcaps for log-like terminals such as github/gitlab CI environments

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, github-actions, ncurses, terminfo

GitLab and GitHub both support coloring their output with escape sequences.

But GitLab (I didn't test the default TERM value in GitHub) sets `TERM=dumb` which is a good default, but techincally incorrect, I guess, as it is misleading about the capabilities.

Is there any predefined terminfo entry which describes the GitLab terminal emulation capabilities correctly, or just better than `dumb`?

If not, is there any way to systematically test the capabilities and write a custom definition?

I understand that a lot of software doesn't use termcaps, and maybe only understands a hardcoded list of `xterm`, `dumb` and `linux`. My goal isn't making it actually working with pre-existing software, there are adhoc options for that often (such as `--color=always`)

Comment: They're probably setting `TERM=dumb` because they don't support cursor-addressing -- and there aren't any widely-used terminal descriptions with *ANSI colors* without cursor-addressing.  You could define one, but might not find it useful.

Comment: Yes, I understand it might not be useful. My goal is more or less to make this shell code work: `[[ -t 1 ]] && (tput setf 2 ; echo should be green; tput setf 7)`. This approach of using colors only on interactive terminals with defined color capabilities is used by many simple apps and scripts (as opposed to full ncurses-based apps). To do this I can use TERM=xterm and create a PTY using e.g. `expect`. This is more about how could I do it the right way instead of merely doing it (e.g. a proper definition instead of xterm). Also setting terminal has no effect as apps detect lack of a TTY.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a simple termcap that at least defines the [known ANSI color capabilities](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/37898), but it would probably need to define all other caps as unsupported, at least until more light can be shone on the other underlying capabilities of GitLab runner terminals.

Example of the supported ANSI color sequences in GitLab CI Runner "terminals": https://gitlab.com/dgoo2308/readability_colors/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml